Ubuntu server 22.04 after setting up static ip-address i cant ping deafult gateway
im quite new to linux and I have tried to set a static ip-address on my ubuntu server 22.04. This is what the /etc/netplan/00-config looks like.
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 100.72.194.68/18
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
     routes:
        - to: default
         via: 100.72.192.1

I am able to ping the ubuntu server from:
Computer A 100.72.193.126
Computer B 100.72.233.67
I can also ssh from computer A
The ubuntu server is unable to ping the router default gateway i just get:

From 100.72.194.68 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

What should i do?
EDIT 1:
I have checked that that /etc/ufw/before.rules have this rule:

-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

Computer A and computer B can both ping the gw 100.72.192.1
Also i now the indentation looks wrong(probably became so when i copyed it over from the ubuntu server) but netplan accepts it so its probably right.
EDIT 2:
Here are the results when i do ip route:
default via 100.72.192.1 dev enp2s0 proto static
100.72.192.0/18 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 100.72.194.68
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-c8bbea4533e3 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
172.27.224.0/23 dev as0t0 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.224.1
172.27.226.0/23 dev as0t1 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.226.1
172.27.228.0/23 dev as0t2 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.228.1
172.27.230.0/23 dev as0t3 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.230.1
172.27.232.0/23 dev as0t4 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.232.1
172.27.234.0/23 dev as0t5 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.234.1
172.27.236.0/23 dev as0t6 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.236.1
172.27.238.0/23 dev as0t7 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.238.1

Here are the results when i do ip addr:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:ee:cb:5e:e4:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 100.72.194.68/18 brd 100.72.255.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9aee:cbff:fe5e:e421/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forev

er

Whats the netmask of the gateway? Can B ping the GW? Does the GW see the packets?

It looks to me that the indentation is wrong for routes and via

I would like to put this as a comment, but I don't have permission for it, so I'm writing here:
Have you tried checking if the interface configuration using the commands, 'ip add' and and 'ip route' ? So you can know if the netplan config file was accepted.

Can you check the ping to  any other host IP in the network from your new Ubuntu server?
By default ping is allowed on Ubuntu, check the rule file at /etc/ufw/before.rules. Make sure the ping outbound is allowed:
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT 

